# NAD27 to WGS84 with proj4js

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, proj, proj4js

I am trying to use proj4js to convert between WGS84 (4326) to NAD27 BLM 14N (ftUS) (32064).  I am using this definition for EPSG 2674

```
`proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +towgs84=-8,161,176 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs "`
```

I have also tried:

```
proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +datum=NAD27 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs "
```

I got the transformation Parameters [from here](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/publications/tr8350.2/wgs84fin.pdf) and have gone through these three similar SO posts [one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80161/on-the-fly-transformation-from-wgs84-to-nad27-with-proj4-code), [two](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49086/getting-the-specified-geographic-transformation-or-at-least-the-gcs-of-a-data), [three](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75419/how-to-transform-data-points-from-wgs84-to-nad27). My `proj4js` transformation remains about 100ft off. I'm validating the result using both corpscon and blue marble.  I can accept the limitations of a 7 parameter transformation but can't find suitable values for the Gulf of Mexico.  3 parameters are not tight enough.  How do I form the proj definition to get this to work.

The coord pair I am using to test is `25.340631, -96.647033` the expected result for `EPSG 26714` is `9201257.09usft,2417471.02usft`.

Comment: Can you provide sample coordinate pairs?

Comment: For the 2nd case, add +nadgrids ? (I'm not sure of the name) Do you have the NADCON grid files installed? On both, the x_0 value should just be 500000, even though that won't make a difference to your offset.

Comment: I would probably also use EPSG:1174 (eastern US) with -9,161,179 or look at EPSG:15852-54 which were developed for the GoM (if that's where the data is)

Comment: @AndreJ I edited my question and included coordinates, @mkennedy I was under the impression that proj4js does not support grid files.   3 parameters `towgs84` is 1-sigma but 7 will get me close enough for what I am doing, I cant find 7 params for GOM though. You are correct I am in  the GOM but  1174 & 15852 are geographic I'm trying to go From WGS84 to a NAD27 projection be it NAD27 UTM XXN or NAD27 BLM XXN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cs2cs (pure proj.4) with `-96.647033 25.340631` in an input file named BLM.txt, I have run these calculations:

```
echo WGS84-32064 (us-ft) >out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:32064 <BLM.txt >>out.txt
echo WGS84-26714 (m) >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:26714 <BLM.txt >>out.txt
echo WGS84-towgs84 >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +towgs84=-8,161,176,0,0,0,0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs <BLM.txt >>out.txt
echo NAD27-grid >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +datum=NAD27 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs <BLM.txt >>out.txt
echo WGS84-tfm15852 (87.25 to 0w)>>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +towgs84=-3,154,177 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs <BLM.txt >>out.txt
echo WGS84-tfm15853 (95 to 87.25w) >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +towgs84=-7,151,175 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs <BLM.txt >>out.txt
echo WGS84-tfm15854 (west of 95w) >>out.txt
cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-99 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000.001016002 +towgs84=-7,151,178 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192 +no_defs <BLM.txt >>out.txt
```

to get these results:

```
WGS84-32064 (us-ft) 
2417471.02  9201257.09 0.00
WGS84-26714 (m) 
736846.64   2804548.77 0.00
WGS84-towgs84 
2417490.04  9201247.36 139.20
NAD27-grid 
2417471.02  9201257.09 0.00
WGS84-tfm15852 (87.25 to 0w)
2417470.98  9201253.01 118.89
WGS84-tfm15853 (95 to 87.25w) 
2417482.69  9201263.98 111.49
WGS84-tfm15854 (west of 95w) 
2417482.85  9201255.09 107.28
```

Your point should lie in the last zone, and the result is about 12 feet from the grid file solution. Plotting the various points on a map with feet grid looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your source for the `+towgs84` values?

Comment: https://www.epsg-registry.org/, tab `retrieve by code`, entering the tfm number. These are kind of "official".